# Double standards with the onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclick

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonForExternalComponent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.externalComponent);

    buttonForExternalComponent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View v){
     startActivity(new Intent(this, A2Activity.class));
}
```

Hi, I'm new to Android. I was trying to add 2 buttons to my example code and ran into a problem...

Well, the code above works. I have two buttons which leads to 2 different activities. One for another class in this package, and another for another component.

However, when I tried to insert both buttons into the onCreate part, the externalComponent works, but doesn't work the same for the class inside the package.

startActivity(new Intent(this, A2Activity.class)); throws an error that it cannot resolve the constructor

```
    buttonForA2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, A2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } 
    });
```

this code does not work.

My question is, is there another listener function for internal activities? I'm confused why the same method doesn't work for the same function.

Thx in advance.

Comment: "this" within a View.onClickListener does not refer to Activity, it refers to a View.onClickListener

Comment: use ActivityName.this instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Stratton pointed out, `this` in `onClickListener` does not point to activity. To fix, you can use this:

```
    final Activity act = this;
    buttonForA2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(act, A2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } 
    });
```